# filter numeric type as string in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I want to add a filter to activeadmin's index page that can filter records by ID, but the default filter options for numeric attributes are equals/greater than/less than while I need the default options for a string attribute contains/equals/starts with/ends with.

I've tried `filter :id, as: :string` but that raises error when filtering.

How can I implement such a filter in activeadmin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me

```
 filter :id_eq, as: :string, label: 'Id'
```

Comment: this only gives me the 'equals' predicate, which is available in the default numeric predicates along with 'greater than' and 'less than'.
I need the default string predicates. thanks for the response though.

Comment: @kirlev, what kind of SQL query do you want to be generated when you talk about ends_with, starts_with ? Can you update your question with example of sql query ? I think it is impossible because of ransack, which is actually generate sql,  has no such feature.

Comment: you are probably right, there is no such feature.
I didn't realize ransack is generating sql.